# Alter current MySql query to combine results based on id

Tags: mysql, select

My current query below gets all the judges who signed up for events. The
subquery in the in clause is because an event can be one or more days and the 
judges can sign up for one or more. This is fine but if its a 2 day event and the judge
signs up for both, their are 2 rows return for the user. I want to combine them so it shows their info plus both event days. How would I go about that?

```
select concat(ej.FirstName, ' ', ej.LastName) as judge, ej.email, ej.phone, ed.EventDate
from EventJudges ej 
inner join EventJudgeXref ejx on ej.Id = ejx.EventJudgeId 
inner join EventDates ed on ejx.EventDateId = ed.Id
where ejx.EventDateId in(SELECT Id FROM EventDates WHERE EventId = 1) 
order by ej.FirstName asc, ej.LastName asc
```

The EventJudgeXref table contains a `JudgeId` and an EventDateId for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `group_concat`:

```
select concat(ej.FirstName, ' ', ej.LastName) as judge,
    ej.email,
    ej.phone,
    group_concat(ed.EventDate) as EventDate
from EventJudges ej 
inner join EventJudgeXref ejx on ej.Id = ejx.EventJudgeId 
inner join EventDates ed on ejx.EventDateId = ed.Id
where ejx.EventDateId in(SELECT Id FROM EventDates WHERE EventId = 1) 
group by ej.Id
order by ej.FirstName asc, ej.LastName asc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c2d6/1)